# Use mail attribute for 802.1x RADIUS authenticatioon with Microsoft NPS

Tags: cisco, authentication, wifi, radius, nps

We have run a Cisco WiFi network that uses 802.1x to authentication logins against Active Directory.

Employees login using their UPN prefix, and all works well.

For various reasons we'd like users to be able to log in with their email address (stored in the `mail` attribute) instead.  This doesn't map to the full UPN (the suffix is different, and our users are from a number of different email domains).

Rather than logging in as they currently do using `firstname.lastname` (which matches the UPN of `firstname.lastname@activedirectory.domain` we want them to use `me@myemail.com` or whatever their email address actually is.

We use Microsoft NPS for this currently, and have our Cisco WLC configured to use it as the RADIUS authentication sever.

Is there a way to change NPS to authentication users based on a different AD/LDAP attribute rather than only sAMAccountName/UPN?

Comment: It seems to me that you could add the email domains as additional UPN suffixes in AD, and then set each users UPN to match their email address.